# How to increase heap size for jmeter in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, jmeter, heap-memory

I tried to increase the heap size for Jmeter in while executing the .jmx file using "JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m" jmeter -t test.jmx [etc.]" command. however, it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

On my Ubuntu , I modified the jmeter script launcher like this: (heap's line)

```
# system's memory availablity:
HEAP="-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m"
```

At the bottom of script , you can see :

```
ARGS="$SERVER $DUMP $HEAP $NEW $SURVIVOR $TENURING $EVACUATION $RMIGC $PERM"

java  $ARGS $JVM_ARGS -jar "`dirname "$0"`/ApacheJMeter.jar" "$@"
```

Comment: What do you call as a jmeter script launcher? Is this file jmeter script launcher “/usr/bin/jmeter”. This file reads as:

#!/bin/sh

# Include the wrappers utility script
. /usr/lib/java-wrappers/java-wrappers.sh
find_jars avalon-framework batik bsf bsh commons-collections3
.
run_java -Djmeter.home=/usr/share/jmeter org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver "$@"

Thanks for the reply in advance.

Comment: Please let me know where should i make changes suggested by you

Comment: jmeter script launcher: "jmeter.sh" in ../bin folder of Jmeter

Comment: Do not set the variables in this script. Instead put them into a script
`setenv.sh` in `JMETER_HOME/bin` to keep your customizations separate.

Answer (score 1):

Create `setenv.sh` in `JMETER_HOME/bin`:  `touch ${JMETER_HOME}/bin/setenv.sh`

Edit file `vi setenv.sh`

To set maximum 8Gb,for example, add line: `HEAP="-Xms512m -Xmx8g"`